# Use of array formulas within VBA

Tags: vba, worksheet-function

Excel array functions in worksheets are useful. E.g. for calculating the average of the sin values of an array A1:A5 I enter the following which works nicely:

```
{=AVERAGE(SIN(A1:A5))}
```

Now I would like to create a function in VBA that does the job, something like:

```
Function MyFunction(r As Variant) As Variant     ' r is the range, e.g. A1:A5 as above  
    MyFunction = WorksheetFunction.Average(Sin(r))  
End Function
```

This function should result in a single value, but it does not work (no matter if I enter it as a normal or array formula in an Excel cell). I thought the problem may be that the VBA sin function is different from the worksheet sin function, but replacing sin by WorksheetFunction.Sin also does not work.

Of course one could find out the number of values, write a loop that stores `sin(r[i=1..n])` values in a temporary array variable and then calculate the average, but I am looking for a more elegent and efficient solution.

Comment: Take a look at the `Range.FormulaArray` property. That might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208529(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast help. However 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E3").FormulaArray = "=Sum(A1:C3)"' works nicely as sub, but not as function. I am looking for a function that can be used also by other users like a normal function with a single cell (or array) result in the cell(s) that it is typed in. Maybe I should also mention that the formula is just a simplified example for a longer one that is used many times per worksheet (otherwise I'd just type it in Excel w/o VBA).

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the `Sin` function expects a single value as a parameter, not an array

Note that VBA function `Sin` is not the same as worksheet function `Sin` (and `Sin` is not a member of the `WorkSheetFunction` object, so `WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Sin(r))` won't work either)

If you change your udf to

```
Function MyFunction(r As Variant) As Variant     ' r is the range, e.g. A1:A5 as above  
    MyFunction = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)  
End Function
```

you will get the average of the specified range, which shows udf's can handle array data.

If you are looking for an efficient method, my advise is to stick with native functions whnever you can (array or otherwise), as a call to a udf, *any udf*, is much slower than native functions.